# Using Axios to send a token to the backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am new to this

I am writing a Vue app that connects to a Wordpress backend and I need to log in. I am using a plugin called Simple JWT-Login and I am able to send the email and password to the back end and i get the JWT back. But trying to log in and sending the jWT back to the back end gets me an error Bad Request.
Here is the function that is supposed to handle the login

```
    async login(){
      try{
        const response = await axios.post('/?rest_route=/simple-jwt-login/v1/auth&email=email&password=password', 
          {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
          }
        );
        const token = response.data.data.jwt
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        console.log(token)
        const login = await axios.get('/?rest_route=/simple-jwt-login/v1/autologin&JWT=token')
        console.log(login)
        // this.$router.push("/");
      } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        // if(err.response.status === 400){
        //   this.error = "Wrong credentials! Please make sure"
        // }
      } finally{
          
      }
    }
```

Comment: I can see that you are calling `axios.post('/?rest_route=/simple-jwt-login/v1` twice. I assume that the first call is for logging in, where you get the token. What are you trying to achieve on the second call?

Comment: The first call is to get the token and the second call is to send the token back. Sorry @Phil not really sure how to answer as i am new to this and trying to figure out how to send the token to the back end so I am logged in. Or am I getting this completely wrong and does the token mean I am logged in and i only use the token to verify me being logged in? Like i say this is new to me

Comment: The plugin documentation talks about authentication and then there is a section about logging in and for that you need the JWT, which is why I call the API twice. I assumed you get the token first ad then use that to log in and get the user back?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a setting in the plugin that the docs does not explain to you and unless you are an expert the only way to find out is by trial and error.

The setting under general for SESSION must be On
[image: simple-jwt-login setting]

Comment: Nice find! If you feel inclined, you could raise an issue against their docs repo

Comment: I did write something on their github page but they never respond so don't think it bothers them. Now I need to find out how I can get the user info and all users and how to edit a post using the API

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [Login User](https://docs.simplejwtlogin.com/#/?id=login-user), it seems you just need to pass the previous `token` value as the `JWT` query parameter.

I've always found it best to use the `params` option in Axios for query params

```js
const login = await axios.get("/", {
  params: {
    rest_route: "/simple-jwt-login/v1/autologin",
    JWT: token,
  }
})
```

Your issue was that in this string...

```js
'/?rest_route=/simple-jwt-login/v1/autologin&JWT=token'
```

`token` was not interpolated; you were literally sending *"token"*.

---

You should do the same with your first request. The `email` and `password` should not be in the query string for this one.

```js
axios.post("/", {
  email: this.email,
  password: this.password,
}, {
  params: {
    rest_route: "/simple-jwt-login/v1/auth",
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the info. That AUTH_KEY you only need if you set the setting to require it. My setting was off. I ran the code with your changes and i am still getting the same error bad request 400

Comment: shouldn't there be a payload for the request. I mean after all you are sending the token? The request shows No payload for this request

Comment: @calvincani I edited the payload for the POST request. Just had to find out if the API supported it (it's not in the docs, had to check in GitHub)

Comment: thanks but my issue is with the GET request and am still getting the bad request error

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `token` value and checking it at https://jwt.io ?

Comment: I just did and I get an error invalid signature. I think it is a setting but the problem is the docs explain like you're a developer and know all the jargon. How do I fix this?

Comment: We are both developers and I'm pretty good with the jargon and as far as I can tell, you're doing everything correctly. You might have better luck looking through their issues list on GitHub

Comment: thanks unfortunately their support is the same as their documentation. I'll keep struggling until I find the answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: @calvincani no worries and best of luck. If you do get it sorted, it might be worth self-answering this question. I'll leave my answer here for now but ping me if you come back to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241709/discussion-between-calvincani-and-phil).